# Spring Config Server properties ordering when directories

Tags: spring, server, config, spring-cloud-config

We are running Spring Cloud Config Server v1.3.1.

We have Bitbucket hosting Git. The Git environment has a configuration folder where we hold our files. There are a number of subdirectories under the configuration folder. eg

```
environment/configuration
application-dev.yml
my-service.yml
my-service-ci.yml
my-service.dev.yml
...

environment/configuration/datasources
application-ci.yml
application-dev.yml
...
```

In the Spring Config Server the application and config server are configured as below:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: "@project.name@"
    cloud:
      config:
        server:
          git:
            uri: https://xxxxx/scm/dep/environment
            basedir: ${baseDirectory}/work
            searchPaths: configuration, configuration/*
```

When loading the my-service Spring Boot app with dev profile I would expect the app specific config files (my-service) to load first. ie

```
environment/configuration/my-service-dev.yml
environment/configuration/my-service.yml
environment/configuration/configuration/application-dev.yml
environment/configuration/application-dev.yml
```

In reality it loads the folders in reverse order so configuration/* comes first with its subdirectories loaded in alphabetical order. Next comes the files
sitting directly under configuration. This gives below order

```
environment/configuration/application-dev.yml
environment/configuration/configuration/application-dev.yml
environment/configuration/my-service-dev.yml
environment/configuration/my-service.yml
```

Spring Boot loads these as a Map containing a list of PropertySources. It iterates from the start and returns the first match. In this case a property in application-dev.yml
would trump the same property in my-service-dev.yml.

Is this intended behaviour or is there a bug when directories are involved?